# how to mount dd image on python?, how to use imagemounter module on windows

Tags: python, mount, dd

i want mount my .dd image file on windows system use python script.
how to mount dd image on python?
I found the "imagemounter" module through the search.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imagemounter
how to use "imagemounter" module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package description tells, its a wrapper around different linux mount types, probably mostly calculating the offset of data in different image formats like vmware and so on. As windows does not support mounting like linux, it won't help you.

You should research tools like daemontools and similiar programs for loop-mounting images on windows.

Comment: Thank you for your kind Answer!